# Duplicate response headers with same values in IIS 8

Tags: duplicates, iis-8, response-headers

We are using IIS 8 for serving static contents and angular UI code for our website. Added some custom headers in web.config recently for security vulnerability fixes. After this change , each custom header that is added is coming 2 times in the response headers.

```
<httpProtocol>
   <customHeaders>
       <add name="X-Content-Type-Options" value="nosniff"/>
   </customHeaders>
</httpProtocol>
```

This issue we are facing only for one request where we are loading home page (index.html>
Can any one help me how to address this one?

I am not sure on what to try for fixing this because the headers are specified in only one place - that is in web.config file.

Comment: Hi, did you restart IIS? also try temporarily remove other custom headers or configurations and see if the duplication persists.

Comment: If I remove custom headers , I am not getting any headers - If I add it any header ,it is coming 2 times - Restart IIS I did not try because some other Apps running..Only custom headers coming 2 times

Comment: You can use failed request tracking to view the detailed request process, in the generated logs, you can view when the response headers were added.

Comment: If I request using "http://devhst01.e2.com/home" it is adding duplicate headers - but if I request index.html directly from URL like "http://devhst01.e2.com/index.html" - then no duplicate headers are coming. Looks like something related to routing only . I will try to trace the logs -but if ARR is adding duplicate headers - how to remove them?

Comment: There are many ways to remove response headers. The first thing you need to do is to figure out what causes duplicate headers to be added, and then choose the appropriate method to remove the esponse headers. about remove unwanted http response headers you can refer to this link: [link](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/iis-support-blog/remove-unwanted-http-response-headers/ba-p/369710).